# Error when installing expo in bare react native project. Build keeps failing

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, expo, android-gradle-plugin

I am fairly new to mobile dev with react native. I started a bare react native project and I'm currently experiencing an error when trying to install expo, so I can use the expo camera library.
Following the docs:
1.https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/#usage
2.https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/sdk-48/packages/expo-camera)

I am currently stuck on step 1:

1. I installed expo modules manually(since I create RN project with npx react-native init) using "npm install expo"
2. I then followed all the steps detailed in link 1 to install expo by changing file content (files shown below)
   As directed by the docs, after changing my files, I did the following after changing the files:

```
npx expo install expo-constants
npx expo run:android
```

I received the following error:

```
› Building app...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\sulei\Desktop\ReactNativeProjects\Instagram\node_modules\expo-application\android\build.gradle' line: 40

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-application'.
> Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for task ':expo-application:androidSourcesJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 4s
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date
Error: C:\Users\sulei\Desktop\ReactNativeProjects\Instagram\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: C:\Users\sulei\Desktop\ReactNativeProjects\Instagram\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\sulei\Desktop\ReactNativeProjects\Instagram\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:52:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at cp.emit (C:\Users\sulei\Desktop\ReactNativeProjects\Instagram\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\sulei\Desktop\ReactNativeProjects\Instagram\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:17:21)        
    at spawnGradleAsync (C:\Users\sulei\Desktop\ReactNativeProjects\Instagram\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:72:46)      
    at Object.assembleAsync (C:\Users\sulei\Desktop\ReactNativeProjects\Instagram\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:52:18)  
    at runAndroidAsync (C:\Users\sulei\Desktop\ReactNativeProjects\Instagram\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.js:31:24)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

build.gradle file in android directory:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter() {
            content {
                includeModule("com.yqritc", "android-scalablevideoview")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

settings.gradle file:

```
rootProject.name = 'Instagram'

apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); 

applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

include ':app'

includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../scripts/autolinking.gradle")
useExpoModules()
```

MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.instagram;
import expo.modules.ReactActivityDelegateWrapper;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegateWrapper(this, BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED, new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
            this,
            getMainComponentName(),
        // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the Fabric Renderer.
            DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getFabricEnabled(), // fabricEnabled
            // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable Concurrent React (i.e. React 18).
            DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getConcurrentReactEnabled() // concurrentRootEnabled

));
}
}
```

MainApplication.java file

```
package com.instagram;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import expo.modules.ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher;
import expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapper;

import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHostWrapper(this, new DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isNewArchEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean isHermesEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
        }
      });

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load();
    }
    ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onApplicationCreate(this);
      }
     
      @Override
      public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onConfigurationChanged(this, newConfig);
  }
}
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Instagram",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^48.0.19",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.6",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/metro-config": "^0.76.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.13",
    "@types/react-native-video": "^5.0.14",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.5",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

I have tried all the steps listed in the docs but I am unsure of what I am missing. Need help

Comment: npx react init is wrong. It should either be npx create-expo-app yourappname or npx react-native@latest init yourappname. https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native&os=linux

Comment: I have the same issue. All the latest versions of react native, expo, gradle seem incompatible. You should try downgrading gradle from version 8 to 7.6. Maybe, that will work for you. Although, that isn’t working for me either. Gives me cmake related error

Comment: @KaranveerSingh Have you figured it out now?

Comment: @Mearaj Hello, that was a typo, I created the bare react native project with npx react-native init projectName.

Comment: Ahh ok. I thought so but wasn't sure. Thanks for letting us know and sorry about that.

Comment: @vividtheapartmentrye not yet. Currently, trying with latest versions of expo like 49.0.0-alpha.6. Getting error: EXUpdates/EXUpdatesAppController.h' file not found.
I think I will have to try with 0.71.8 and wait for expo to release stable updates. Expo just isnt compatible with React Native 0.72.0 it seems.